# React native expo :How to send to json array using fetch,POST method

Tags: arrays, json, fetch, expo

i have json array value,now i need to send that json array value ,using POST method through fetch().

```
example:
    fetch("/echo/json/",
    {
     headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify([{id:1,name:'aaa'},{id:2,name:'bbb'}])
    })
   .then(function(res){ console.log(res) })
   .catch(function(res){ console.log(res) })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know how your end point is structured, but you can try to send an object with the array, like so:

```js
JSON.stringify({data: [{id:1,name:'aaa'},{id:2,name:'bbb'}]})
```

this will give you this JSON:

```js
{
  "data":[ 
    {"id":1,"name":"aaa"},
    {"id":2,"name":"bbb"}
  ]
}
```

if it doesnt work please tell me what your end point takes :)

Comment: thanks for response,i already got solution.same way i already applied .